# Remove duplicates rows from large csv with multiline fields

Tags: csv, awk

Given the following csv, with multiline fields:

```
"id","text"
"1","line 1
line 2"
"2","line 1
line 2"
"1","line 1
line 2"
```

... which displays as:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | line 1 line 2 |
| 2 | line 1 line 2 |
| 1 | line 1 line 2 |

If I use the following `awk` command to remove duplicate rows from this csv based on the id (column 1):

```
awk -F, '!x[$1]++' 'file-01.csv' > 'file-01-deduped.csv'
```

I end up with:

```
"id","text"
"1","line 1
line 2"
"2","line 1
```

which displays as:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | line 1 line 2 |
| 2 | line 1 |

This is an oversimplified example, but it seems `awk` doesn't play well with multiline fields. Perhaps I'm missing something though.

Additional info: I'm writing these csv's according to [RFC4180 standards](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2)—most notably, fields containing line breaks, double quotes, and commas are enclosed in double-quotes. And double quotes appearing inside a field are escaped with a preceding double quote.

Also, I'm writing the csv in Node/JS, but I found `awk` to be a really simple/fast way to dedupe very large files in the past—none had multiline fields though.

I'm by no means bound to `awk`—I'm open to any/all suggestions—just wanted to be clear about what I've tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need a CSV-aware tool to properly handle the line breaks inside the rows.

[GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases) was made for this: it's fast, pretty good w/memory, is CSV savvy, and is pre-built for a number of platforms.

Its [unique subcommand](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#unique) will keep only the first row based on the occurrence of a value or set of values in a column or set of columns.

To drop duplicate rows based on the text column:

```sh
gocsv unique -c 'text' input.csv > de-duped.csv
```

It can even tell you how many dupes it found along the way:

```sh
gocsv unique -c 'text' -count input.csv > de-duped.csv
```

How fast, how good w/memory?.

I mocked up a 1_000_000 row CSV with two columns of random text and embedded line breaks (also includes commas and quoted quotes):

```sh
ll -h gen_1000000x3.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 zyoung  staff    52M Apr 26 09:36 gen_1000000x3.csv

cat gen_1000000x3.csv
ID,Col1,Col2
0,"ddddd
 "","" oooooo","wwwwww
 "","" nnnnnnn"
1,"llllllll
 "","" ccccccc","iiiiiiii
 "","" wwwww"
2,"nnnnn
 "","" iiiiiiii","ooooo
 "","" kkkkkkkk"
...
```

On my M1 MacBook Air, de-duping the 1-million row, 52 MB CSV took a half-second and consumed only 13 MB of memory:

```
/usr/bin/time -l gocsv unique -c Col2 gen_1000000x3.csv  > de-duped.csv       
        0.45 real         0.49 user         0.05 sys
            ...
            13124608  peak memory footprint
```

Over 989_000 duplicate rows were dropped:

```sh
gocsv dims de-duped.csv 
Dimensions:
  Rows: 10816
  Columns: 3
```

We can count instances of each of value in Col2 that was found (counting consumed 175 MB of memory):

```sh
gocsv unique -c Col2 -count gen_1000000x3.csv  > de-duped.csv
```

GoCSV can also display multi-line rows in the terminal:

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| ID     | Col1          | Col2          | Count |
+--------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| 0      | ddddd         | wwwwww        | 80    |
|        |  "," oooooo   |  "," nnnnnnn  |       |
+--------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| 1      | llllllll      | iiiiiiii      | 89    |
|        |  "," ccccccc  |  "," wwwww    |       |
+--------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| 2      | nnnnn         | ooooo         | 97    |
|        |  "," iiiiiiii |  "," kkkkkkkk |       |
...
```

I cannot compare the awk scripts suggested so far: one just doesn't do anything in my terminal, and the other requires GNU which I don't have. But awk will come out slower: 3x longer just to run `awk '{print $0}' gen_1000000x3.csv > /dev/null`, and that's not even doing meaningful work. And the hoops you have to jump through to try and program a CSV parser from scratch.

Comment: this worked out nicely for me. super fast too and maintains RFC4180 standards. the added functionalities (subcommands and their args) are very useful—i can see this continuing to be an extremely helpful tool

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk -F',' '
FNR>1{
  sub(/^"/,"",$2)
  sub(/"$/,"",$3)
  gsub(/"/,"",$1)
  print $1 OFS $2 ORS "  " $3
}
' <(awk '{printf("%s%s",$0!~/^"/?",":FNR>1?ORS:"",$0)} END{print ""}' Input_file)
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, running 1st `awk` to print all lines in single row(wherever it has line not started from `"`) and sending its output as an input to main `awk` where printing the required values of id and all line values as per requirement.

Comment: `awk '{printf("%s%s",$0!~/^"/?",":FNR>1?ORS:"",$0)} END{print ""}' foo.csv` prints my two row sample CSV on a single line, but when I run the bigger script I get nothing. I'm running awk on BSD (macOS).

Comment: I'm also getting a warning from shell-check, `In POSIX sh, process substitution is undefined.shellcheck(SC3001)`. What shellls does this solution require?

Comment: @ZachYoung, i haven't tested it in Mac os it uses process substitution mechanism it worked fine for me for shown samples in Ubuntu server. If process substitution is supported then it should work IMHO 

Comment: I can see it working, takes about 4 seconds to run against a 1_000_000 sample CSV I mocked up, but I get no output, so I cannot say what it's doing.

Comment: @ZachYoung, so you mean for bigger files it's not working? May be need to check memory of server also if that is less then we need to check on this one. I haven't checked on huge files but could check it later on how it goes  but my I believe it shouldn't be much slow IMHO but need to check it, will try to check in morning once I get time 

Comment: No, I just mentioned the 1-million row CSV because I could meaningfully time it. I started with a simple two-row CSV and same result, no output.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i had the same issues as @ZachYoung—seems we're running similar machines so perhaps related to that. appreciate your answer though 

Comment: @burgerpe24, not sure, it has worked fine for me, thanks for letting know though. Sorry couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is not csv aware, so it's not really the right tool for the job. There are a few csv implementations floating around the internets, maybe you could take a look at them.

You did mention the file being large, but if it fits your memory, this is a variation of something I needed a few weeks back. It's GNU awk using `FPAT` so it's not really fast:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    RS="^$"                                # read in whole file
    FPAT="([^,\n]*)|(\"(\"\"|[^\"])+\")"   # regex magic
    OFS=","
}
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)                     # iterate fields 2 at a time
        if(!a[$i]++)                       # if first field not seen before
            print $i,$(i+1)                # output 2 fields
}' file
```

Test data:

```
"id","text"
"1","line 1
line 2"
"2","line 1
line 2"
"3"," ""line 1""
line 2"
"4",""
"5","line 1,
line 2"
"1","line 1
line 2"
```

Output:

```
"id","text"
"1","line 1
line 2"
"2","line 1
line 2"
"3"," ""line 1""
line 2"
"4",""
"5","line 1,
line 2"
```

I don't know how many ways it can fail you, tho.

Answer (score 1):

A great and very simple  tool CSV aware is [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/).
Running

```
mlr --csv uniq -a input.csv >output.csv
```

You will have

```
id,text
1,"line 1
line 2"
2,"line 1
line 2"
```

It has also a great documentation: this is the one for the [`uniq` verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#uniq).